# jQuery attribute selectors: How to query for an attribute with a custom namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have a simple XHTML document that uses a custom namespace for attributes:

```
<html xmlns="..." xmlns:custom="http://www.example.com/ns">
    ...
    <div class="foo" custom:attr="bla"/>
    ...
</html>
```

How do I match each element that has a certain custom attribute using jQuery? Using

```
$("div[custom:attr]")
```

does not work. (Tried with Firefox only, so far.)

Comment: Update, Suphi's answer is a much simpler syntax and works. I have not done any performance comparisons though.

Comment: Is the namespace prefix declaration supposed to be xmlns:custom= ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[jQuery](https://jquery.com/) does not support custom namespaces directly, but you can find the divs you are looking for by using filter function.

```
// find all divs that have custom:attr
$('div').filter(function() { return $(this).attr('custom:attr'); }).each(function() {
  // matched a div with custom::attr
  $(this).html('I was found.');
});
```

Answer (score 19):

This works in some conditions:

`$("div[custom\\:attr]")`

However, for a more advanced method, see [this XML Namespace jQuery plug-in](http://www.rfk.id.au/blog/entry/xmlns-selectors-jquery)

Comment: The namespace plug-in is a dream.

Comment: This strategy is not working in Webkit based browsers like Safari & Chrome. Any idea?

Comment: +1, with a little side note: jQuery will clobber namespace definitions of appended XML chunks it HTML (tested with SVG, actually). It mangles attributes `xmlns:custom="uri"` into `custom="uri"`, probably because HTML does not (generally?) acknowledge the `xmlns` attribute. Serving the document as XHTML fixes the problem, though may not be practical in all cases.

Comment: In my experience, it is typically the browser itself that is responsible for mangling the HTML (since it manages the DOM, not jQuery). IE is especially  terrible about this (big surprise).

Answer (score 6):

the syntax for matching by attribute is:

`$("div[customattr=bla]")` matches `div customattr="bla"`

`$("[customattr]")` matches all tags with the attribute `"customattr"`

with namespace attributes like `'custom:attr'` its not working

[Here](http://www.pamaya.com/jquery-selectors-and-attribute-selectors-reference-and-examples/) you can find a good overview.

Comment: The linked article does not reference custom attributes.

Comment: This isn't an answer.  It's basically just restating the question and saying that selectors don't seem to work with namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `$('div').attr('custom:attr')`.

Comment: I clarified my questin: I want to match each element that has a custom attribute, not get the value of the attribute.

Comment: @redsquare: This works for most of browsers but fails at Opera. Any quick fix for that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation of a custom selector that works for me.

```
// Custom jQuery selector to select on custom namespaced attributes
$.expr[':'].nsAttr = function(obj, index, meta, stack) {

    // if the parameter isn't a string, the selector is invalid, 
    // so always return false.
    if ( typeof meta[3] != 'string' )
        return false;

    // if the parameter doesn't have an '=' character in it, 
    // assume it is an attribute name with no value, 
    // and match all elements that have only that attribute name.
    if ( meta[3].indexOf('=') == -1 )
    {
        var val = $(obj).attr(meta[3]);
        return (typeof val !== 'undefined' && val !== false);
    }
    // if the parameter does contain an '=' character, 
    // we should only match elements that have an attribute 
    // with a matching name and value.
    else
    {
        // split the parameter into name/value pairs
        var arr = meta[3].split('=', 2);
        var attrName  = arr[0];
        var attrValue = arr[1];

        // if the current object has an attribute matching the specified 
        // name & value, include it in our selection.
        return ( $(obj).attr(attrName) == attrValue );
    }
};
```

Example usage:

```
// Show all divs where the custom attribute matches both name and value.
$('div:nsAttr(MyNameSpace:customAttr=someValue)').show();

// Show all divs that have the custom attribute, regardless of its value.
$('div:nsAttr(MyNameSpace:customAttr)').show();
```