# jQuery - How to select by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML like this,

```
<a id="a_1" href="#" disabled_onclick="true">Link1</a>
<a id="a_2" href="#">Link2</a>
<a id="a_3" href="#" disabled_onclick="true">Link3</a>
<input id="b_1" type="submit" disabled_onclick="true">Button1</input>
<input id="b_2" type="submit">Button2</input>
<input id="b_3" type="submit">Button3</input>
```

Now I need write a jQuery which returns me all the attributes in my html having a disabled_onclick property set to true. In this case, I should get 3 elements, two link tags and one input tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery attribute selectors: How to query for an attribute with a custom namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91518/jquery-attribute-selectors-how-to-query-for-an-attribute-with-a-custom-namespac)

Comment: why are you closing <input... tag with </button> ?????

Comment: i guessed but still commented to bring in notice..

Comment: @dku.rajkumar: You could have edited given your reputation :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)’s how to select all those elements:

```
$('[disabled_onclick="true"]');
```

Since [`true` is a valid unquoted attribute value in CSS](http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes#true), you could even [omit the quotes](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values):

```
$('[disabled_onclick=true]');
```

If you care about valid HTML you should consider using a custom `data-*` attribute instead though.

```
<input id="b_1" type="submit" disabled_onclick="true">
<!-- …becomes… -->
<input id="b_1" type="submit" data-disabled-onclick="true">
```

That way it’s valid HTML, and you’ll still be able to select it as follows:

```
$('[data-disabled-onclick="true"]');
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$('[disabled_onclick="true"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[disabled_onclick="true"]');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

In the above line, you'd only query for `input nodes`, you can omit the `input` which would then query over all nodes in your entire markup (which is probably kind of slow'ish).

```
$('[disabled_onclick="true"]');
```

Comment: I don think it will return <a> tag too.

Comment: this selects only `input` tags and not `a` tags

Comment: @jAndy: I commented before you edited your answer, anyways, I'll take -1 back since your current answer is correct

Comment: @dku.rajkumar: yes, exactly. You figured it out correctly. You win.

Comment: @jAndy now what do you say.. i think you should not take it.. our intention was not to pin point you, just to make correction.

Comment: Was gonna upvote, but after reading the comments, decided not to... :(