# How to select elements with the same attribute value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Say I have a structure like so:

```
<div data-stuff="foo"></div>
<div data-stuff="foo"></div>
<div data-stuff="foo"></div>
<div data-stuff="bar"></div>
<div data-stuff="bar"></div>
<div data-stuff="bar"></div>
<div data-stuff="baz"></div>
```

And I want to hide all the divs with the same attribute except the first, so I'd get:

```
<div data-stuff="foo"></div>
<div data-stuff="bar"></div>
<div data-stuff="baz"></div>
```

Now I know I could just do this:

```
$('[data-stuff=foo]:gt(0), [data-stuff=bar]:gt(0), [data-stuff=baz]:gt(0)').hide();
```

The problem is, the value of `data-stuff` is dynamically generated and is unpredictable. What could I do to accomplish this task?

**EDIT**

The DOM elements themselves aren't necessarily the same, so $.unique() won't help here. It's also important that the FIRST is the one that remains showing, so reordering can't happen.

Comment: P.S. `$.unique` doesn't work the way you think it does.  `$.unique` is for arrays of DOM elements, jQuery uses this internally when making jQuery objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - How to select by attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210073/jquery-how-to-select-by-attribute)

Comment: Why can't you execute the code above when the `rel` is changed?

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I now I had used it once at some point, but couldn't quite remember the context. I thought it had been something to the extent of `$.unique($('div'))` but I must have been mistaken. Thanks again!

Comment: @Diodeus, the attribute is not a given, it's dynamic. I explained this in the question.

Comment: @JKirchartz, I don't believe I understand. The content is initially loaded straight from the server.

Comment: @KyleMacey why can't you use the jQuery you posted in the question?

Comment: @JKirchartz Again, the value to `rel` is dynamic. It's ok, though, I got some good answers here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The brute force way:

```
var found = {};

$("[rel]").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var rel = $this.attr("rel");

    if(found[rel]){
        $this.hide();
    }else{
        found[rel] = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 yeah this is what I was thinking.  I don't know if there is a selector for this per say...

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this:

```
$('div[rel]:visible').each(function(){
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(this).nextAll('div[rel="'+rel+'"]').hide();
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/CsTQT/

Comment: Note that `nextAll` only works for siblings, so if the html structure is actually more complex than the posted example, this may not work.

Comment: Unforunately, @JamesMontagne is right. I should have taken this into consideration for my question and I apologized. I'd +2 if I could though for having the jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `rel` is not used for storing data. According to the W3C, rel describes "the relationship from the current document to the anchor specified by the href attribute. The value of this attribute is a space-separated list of link types."

Secondly, `rel` is only an attribute on `<a>` and `<link>`.  You really want to be using the `data-*` HTML5 attribute. Don't worry about browser support, it works all the way back to IE 66 (probably 5).

This will be accessable via the JQuery `$.data('name')` function.

```
<div data-foo="bar"></div>
```

will be accessable via:

```
$('div').filter(function(inputs){
    return $(this).data('foo') === 'bar';
}).hide()
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm not actually using rel. I had an example in my code snippets that used the same thing with anchor tags, and it was a quick copy and paste then as an afterthought I changed them to DIVs. Good catch, though

Answer (score 0):

That is means : if you select the first element , you want to hide each brothers ; 
So use `JBrothersByAttr` jquery plugin  which is a part of  [Mounawa3et `منوعات` Jquery plugin](https://github.com/abdennour/------):

```
$('[data-stuff=foo]:eq(0)').brothersByAttr('data-stuff').hide();
$('[data-stuff=bar]:eq(0)').brothersByAttr('data-stuff').hide();
$('[data-stuff=baz]:eq(0)').brothersByAttr('data-stuff').hide();
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/7ypEa/1/

**Explanation :**
1. select the first via `:eq(0)`

```
   var jq= $('[data-stuff=foo]:eq(0)')
```

2.select the others elements that have the same value of `data-stuff` attr via `JBrothersByAttr` :

```
   var brothers=jq.brothersByAttr('data-stuff')
```

3.Hide it

```
brothers.hide()
```