# Get element by a specific data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

Is there a way to grab a whole element by one of its data attributes via javascript or jQuery? Say i have a link somewhere on a website like this

`<a href="http://www.google.com/" data-source="google">Google</a>`

Since the link above doesn't have any id or class i cannot grab it by that. I need to get it by its `data-source` attribute. So say i could somehow with jQuery get the value of a attribute with the name of `data-source`. How would i do that ?

Comment: Try `$('[data-source]')` ... simple css selector ;)

Comment: This has been asked a few times before. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210073/jquery-how-to-select-by-attribute) is another example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('[data-source="google"]')
```

This will select all elements which `data-source` attribute equals to `google`.

See [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).