# How to add css property to element has specific attribute using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, jquery-attribute-equals

i need to add css property in this div using jquery, but i need to use only attribute value (`dashboard_1_widget_3`) to add css property.

```
<section class="widget grid-stack-item grid-stack-item-content" widget-token="dashboard_1_widget_3">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - How to select by attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210073/jquery-how-to-select-by-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Attribute Equals Selector `[name=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select element has specific attribute contain specific value. Also use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to add css property to selected element.

```
$("section[widget-token='dashboard_1_widget_3']").css("color", "red");
```

```js
$("section[widget-token='dashboard_1_widget_3']").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section widget-token="dashboard_1_widget_1">Section 1</section>
<section widget-token="dashboard_1_widget_3">Section 2</section>
<section>Section 3</section>
```